# Data Storage (Date, Time and Button Id) into some text file and editing that file for Logging

Tags: android, eclipse

1. I want to store the current data/time and the Button Id into some file.
2. Currently, I am doing this with Internal Storage, but this is not working for me.
3. I am able to store the String (as most of us can find in various tutorials) but I am not able to store the Date/time and button id. For String, we can easily use fos.write(string.getbyte[]).
4. Another thing that I want to do is after storing the data into the file, I want to access that file so that I can manipulate data from it.

Eg. There are few buttons, TV_ON, TV_OFF, DVD_ON, etc. If I will click TV_ON button, it will store the Button Id and at what time that button is pressed. And if TV_OFF is pressed, it will store the corresponding Id and Time. So that I can get the duration for which TV was ON. This way I will able to interpret Energy Consumed during that duration (Using some calculations).

Please Guide !!

Comment: "I am able to store the String (as most of us can find in various tutorials) but I am not able to store the Date/time and button id". This doesn't make sense, why can't you store Date/time, button id?

Comment: I tried. using 
Date d = new Date();
fos.write(Log.i(tag, ""+ d));
when i am accessing the file using DDMS, it is showing "(" only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert a `Date` to `String` using a `formatter` because same date could be represented in many different ways. Printing button id is straightforward:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String logMsg = "Date: " + formatter.format(date) + " Button id: " + R.id.your_button_id;
Log.i(tag, logMsg);
fos.write(logMsg);
```

Comment: It worked. But i converted Date using different commands.
Date d = new Date();
Log.i(tag, ""+ d);
byte []buf = (d+"").getBytes();

Ok i have this date into the File. But how to access the file? I am not able to access using Internal Storage...
Can we access using External Storage?

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use Android's built-in Log utility. Once you've done your logging, you can get the log file off the device. It wasn't clear whether you wanted to modify the log file at run time or afterwards.

An example:

```
//For information
String date = getDate(); //put your date here
Button id = R.id.your_button_id
Log.i(logTag, "Date is: " + date + " - Button id: " + id);
```

Other logging levels include:

```
Log.d(String, String) //for debugging
Log.w(String, String) //for warnings
Log.e(String, String) //for errors
```

Logging output looks like this

```
07-17 14:03:39.670: I/[my logtag](1810): [my message]
```